# Git winmerge pop up "select files and folders" appearing

Tags: java, git, merge

I am merging my branch `A` to branch `B`.

I am on branch `B` and I used the following command: `git merge --squash A`
and it told me that I have conflicts that I have to resolve so I ran the following command: `git mergetool -t winmerge`.

My winmerge window appeared, however, there is some pop up on my winmerge now asking "Select files or folders". This pop up never appeared before. It always just opened the winmerge window with the diff of the conflicted files.

Why is that pop up appearing and how do I get it back to the default settings of the winmerge window appearing without that pop up?

I have a picture below:

[image]

Comment: Can you show how your config is set? (only the mergetool section, get it with something like `git config -l | grep mergetool`)

Answer (score 2):

Actually I figured it out.

My .gitconfig file for some reason had two merge tool set, like the following:

```
mergetool "p4merge"]
    path = c:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Perforce/p4merge.exe

[mergetool "winmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinMerge\\WinMergeU.exe\" -e -u -dl \"Base\" -dr 
    \"Mine\" \"\" \"\" \"\"
```

so I removed the `p4merge` and used the following config below [https://gist.github.com/shawndumas/6158524]

Comment: So glad "you" figured it out without any hint from anyone ;-p Meh, just kidding, take care.

Comment: @RomainVALERI haha, if you want to put your comment as an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: Yours is fine, and it's ticking time :-)